# Selenium Webdirver unable to bind to locking port

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I know there are multiples questions related to this title already on Stackoverflow, but I didn't find out a workable solution.
I'm bored by this message so much:

> An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException'
>   occurred in WebDriver.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within
>   45000 ms

Please let me know if you got something can fix this other than restart my server time and time again.

By the way, I'm using C# on Selenium 2.37, and Firefox v19.

I appreciate any help related.

Comment: @user1177636 I don't use IE and Chrome a lot, but it happens on newer version of Firefox also.

Comment: There are a lot of duplicate questions for this, but I had hard time finding a reliable solution.